# How can I get flyway CLI to list all validation failures rather than stopping at the first failure

Tags: database-migration, flyway

Using Flyway CLI 4.1.2
If I call `validate` and there are multiple files that have a checksum mismatch, for instance, flyway only reports the first one:

```
ERROR: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 2021.01.01
```

if I fix that and run flyway validate again, it will stop at the next error

```
ERROR: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 2021.01.02
```

What I would like is to see a complete list of all the validation failures at once, rather than having to play whack-a-mole. Something like

```
ERROR: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 2021.01.01
ERROR: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration 2021.01.02
ERROR: Validate failed: Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 2021.01.03
ERROR: Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 2021.01.04
```

I had a look at the [configuration parameters](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/) in the documentation, but I can't find anything that looks right.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Listing all validation failures is the standard behaviour in more recent Flyway - it was added at 6.0.3 and we're now on 7.11.x. Have you considered upgrading, as v4.1 is somewhat elderly?